# How can we refer to someone's eyes?

Tags: sentence-construction

When we used the word "look", mostly it refers to someone's (his/her) overall appearance.
But how can I use this word properly in order to imply or to refer to someone's eyes..?
Should I use always "eyes" as a subject or should I use a preposition or adverb?

To make it clear I wrote some sentences:

> 1. You look good = You look presentable = You are good-looking
> 2. You look well = You look healthy
> 3. You look happy = Your body looks happy (here eyes also can show the experience of happiness besides face and body)

But when I try to say:

*a.*

> You look so deep, meaningful, tired. (**Could it connote only eyes?**)

Should I say

> "Your eyes look so deeply, meaningfully, tiredly"

*b.*

> I can see tiredness in your look. (**Could it connote only eyes?**)

Should I say

> "I can see the tiredness in your eyes"

or should I say

> "The look in your eyes shows how tired you are"

Answer (score 2):

*"Your eyes look so deeply,meaningfully, tiredly"  are all incorrect syntactically.

The "ly" suffix should not be there - regardless of the questionably semantics.

You can say:

1. Your eyes look tired

That is very natural and common.

Saying:

1. Your eyes look deep
2. Your eyes look meaningful

Are both grammatically correct, but are metaphors - and quite poetic ones.  For some reason "your eyes look deep" seems much much better than "your eyes look meaningful" as a figurative expression.  I would not recommend "your eyes look meaningful" - even in a poem.

(I am a native Australian English speaker, but not a poet)

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I made some researches on the internet again after I had readanswers and  found out that people can say/write either " he looked deeply into my eyes" or "he looked deep into my eye" . So are both correct?

Comment: "he looked deeply into my eyes" is much more common.   It would be grammatically correct to say "he looked deeply into my eye", but it would only be used if you were describing a visit to the optometrist. :-)

Comment: "he looked deep into my eye[s]" would suggest the AmE habit of forgetting to use -ly on an adjective. Think Different ;)

Answer (score 1):

We have an expression for that: "Your eyes look tired."

That only works for the word "tired" though, don't try saying "your eyes look meaningful" as that sounds very odd in English!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.How about "your eyes look meaningfully". You can imply in lyrical way.

Comment: That makes sense alright @Murat, but it's not even close to "look meaningful" in any ways.

Comment: @Murat No good. We just don't describe eyes as 'meaningful' in English. However, you COULD say "your eyes look beautiful", "your eyes look sore", and "your eyes look red"; that's because in English we don't describe eyes using metaphors. You wouldn't say "your arm looks meaningful"!

Comment: You could use 'gaze' 'stare' 'expression' - anything that isn't actually eyes.

Comment: @Mark I think I get what you mean.I wouldn't say "your arm looks meaningful"  and when we say "your eyes look beautiful", probably she/he has a unique colour of eyes.But hopefully you understand what I try to say. When I say "your eyes look meaningful/meaningfully" it is completely figuratively. Maybe  it could still sound uncolloquial when even we think and take it figuratively maybe because of the word "meaningful". But consider I write down a piece of poem and say "your eyes looks deeply" .I don't mean "your eyes are deep  physically/literally.They just "tell" a lot even they cannot talk

Comment: @Murat I completely understand what you're saying, but we just don't ever describe eyes in a figurative way. If you're writing poetry, use similes instead: "your eyes are as deep as the dark abyss of the ocean". That sort of thing.

Comment: @Mark Thank you.How about "Your eyes look like coming home"

Comment: @Murat I'm afraid not. The closest I can think of would be "When I look into your eyes, I get that same feeling I get when I'm coming home."

Comment: @Mark Actually this sentence belongs to a song by Taylor Swift,who is an American singer. It is too lyrical?

Comment: @Murat Oh yeah, that's interesting, but I wouldn't follow her example. I said people don't describe eyes in a figurative way, so she's doing it anyway to be artistic.

Comment: The eyes look or gaze at something or someone. We can say *He looked meaningfully into her eyes.*  But this would be verging on the comical: *His eyes looked meaningfully into her eyes.*